# CSS, SVG image containing letters don't work when trying stroke-dasharray

Tags: html, css, web, animation, svg

I have a problem with creating an animation while using the SVG image which uses paths for letters. I tried using nth-child for each letter and then stroke-dasharray for removing a part of each letter but it didn't work, I don't even know why. I would like to get some help. I am creating my website in HTML and CSS. Obviously my HTML code is connected to the CSS code, before I didn't have problems like this. Here is my code from CSS. In HTML I used svg and id="logo".

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#logo path:nth-child(1){
    stroke-dasharray: 200px;
    stroke-dasharray: 50px;
}

#logo path:nth-child(2){

}
```

Comment: What image would that be?

Comment: Please add your HTML/SVG to the question.